# CSS: How to detect the OLD Edge BUT NOT THE NEW Edge Chromium?

Tags: css, browser, microsoft-edge, chromium

Is there a way to handle the **old** Edge seperatly from the **new** Edge Chromium in CSS?

For the pre-Chromium versions I've used the following snippet so far:

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  .selector {
    property: value;
  }
}
```

Now I need to make sure that this affects only the OLD Edge and that the new Chromium based Edge will ignore these lines.

Can someone confirm this? I havent't found any information on this topic so far and I don't have the new Edge in the office (and the page I am going to build these days is behind a firewall)

Comment: Why would you need that info? You can treat the new Edge like Chrome

Comment: a really!? That means, no extra code treats the new Edge as it is (like Google Chrome) and with the code shown above I can still catch the old version, right? That's supercool then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Edge is Chromium-based so it's like Chrome. You can still use that CSS rule to target Edge Legacy and it won't affect Edge Chromium.

I made a simple sample like this:

```css
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  #aaa {
    background-color: yellow
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px; height:200px" id="aaa">
  aaa
</div>
```

The result in Edge Chromium is like this:

[image]